Cosmos DB connection string is invalid The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character more than two padding characters
Getting below error while connecting to cosmos db:
Message: Error with data source: Cosmos DB connection string is invalid. The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.  Please adjust your data source definition in order to proceed.

Connection string is:
AccountEndpoint=https://candidatenosql.documents.azure.com;AccountKey=JMVUIYDlLmXTprx5LEglrqA3CFVhhilu5Pga9dji7v0XCnmhQLdjcHd8PTVXBOVmQTK7HHr8NRTdACDbGP5tXw==

please share correct way to configure Azure CosmosDB NOSQL database azure

Could you please provide the smaple code which is connecting to cosmos db?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Message: Error with data source: Cosmos DB connection string is invalid. The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.  Please adjust your data source definition in order to proceed.

The above error occurs because of passing the invalid connection string. Make sure to provide valid connection string of the Azure Cosmos DB and check whether the service is accessible or deleted. Follow the below code to connect with Azure Cosmos DB NoSQL.
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient

connectionString = "AccountEndpoint=https://****.documents.azure.com;AccountKey=*****"
client = CosmosClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

dbName = "newDb"
containerName = "newCont"
database = client.get_database_client(dbName)
container = database.get_container_client(containerName)

query = "SELECT * FROM c"  

items = list(container.query_items(query=query, enable_cross_partition_query=True))

for item in items:
    print(item)


